# Is the lack of sequence convergence preserved by continuous functions from a metric space to $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis

Say I have a metric space $X$ and a function $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is continuous and bounded. If I have a sequence $(x_n) \in X$ that does not converge, is it true that the sequence $f(x_1),f(x_2),\cdots$ does not coverge as well.

The converse of this statement is true by virtue of $f$ being continuous, but I am having trouble constructing either a counterexample to this statement or proving it.

Comment: If $f$ is constant...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are counterexamples *even if* $f$ is one-to-one. Define $f: \mathbb{R} \to [-1,1]$ given by $f(x) = \frac{2}{\pi} \arctan(x)$. Then $f$ is continuous and bounded. Consider $x_n := n$. Then it is easy to see that $f(x_n) \to 1$. But clearly $x_n$ is not convergent.

Answer (score 2):

There are easy counterexamples where $f$ is not one-to-one.  If, say, $f(a) = f(b)$ with $a \ne b$, then you could have $x_n$ alternating between $a$ and $b$, therefore not converging, but $f(x_n)$ is a constant sequence, therefore converges.